# What is the meaning of comma sequence like ,,,,, in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I recently came across the following Solidity function:

```
function testHealthFactor() public {
        (, , , , , uint256 healthFactor) = ILendingPool(lendingPool).getUserAccountData(user);
        console.log("health factor", healthFactor);
        assertEq(healthFactor < 1 ether, true);
    }
```

I don't know Solidity enought yet, so I wander what is the mining of that sequence of 5 commas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solidity allows you to return multiple values within a function. If you don't need these values, you can omit them, and move to the next with the `,`.

For example:

```
function returnStuff() public returns (uint256, uint256) {
   return (1, 3);
}

( , uint256 ourNum) = returnStuff();
// ourNum = 3
```

Comment: do you also know if that practice will also "optimize" the contract in terms of gas fee consumption?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but since you're using less variables I can imagine it helps with gas fees.